# Identify which link has been clicked and load a particular page with ajax based on the clicked link

Tags: ajax

I have a list of links and would like to use ajax to identify which link has clicked and based on the link clicked load a file in a designated container on the same page. for example:

link 1 
link 2
link 3

if any of link 1 is clicked fetch link1.html and place it  or
if any of link 3 is clicked fetch link3.html and place it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery you could use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#resultDiv').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

and with plain javascript you could use the [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method to fetch all anchors and then subscribe for the onclick event and inside send the ajax request:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = function() {

            var url = this.href;

            // TODO: use the url to send an AJAX request

            return false;
        };
    }
};
```